# Can't connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, authentication, tfs

I've been happily using Team Foundation Server with Visual Studio 2010 for the last couple of months at my current place of work when it has suddenly stopped working. I get the following errors:

[image: Error]

[image]

If I browse to the wiki (Sharepoint) on the TFS server it works fine in Firefox but in Internet Explorer it fails with:

> No authority could be contacted for authentication.

I'm not aware of any changes to the server or my machine that would cause the errors and other users of TFS are not affected.

The TFS server is on a different domain to my machine, but usually I get prompted to login and using a domain prefixed username works. At the moment, I don't even get a login prompt anymore.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does it respond to WS? http://tfs_server_name:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/serverstatus.asmx

Comment: No. I tried to add a service reference in Visual Studio, but it fails with the same error. However, the Add Service Reference dialog doesn't seem to give me a way to enter credentials which I'd need to do since it is on a different domain.

Comment: After a few days the problem disappeared, only to return a few weeks later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used a workaround to get past this problem. We configured an entry in the **Windows Stored User Names and Passwords** tool for the domain of the TFS server. It got around the  problem of TFS not prompting for credentials by explicitly supplying them via this tool.

[image: Stored User Names and Passwords]
[image: Add an entry]

When you change your password for that domain account, you must also change the password here otherwise your account can be locked after failing authentication too many times.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started to experience a similar issue. We also host TFS on a different domain.   Twice in the last week TFS has stopped authenticating users, and I have received messages similar to above. I have no idea what is causing this, but on each occasion SQL Server Agent service was stopped. A reboot of the server and a manual restart of SQL Server agent seems to fix the problem temporarily. I'm not sure if this information is helpful, but I would also really appreciate any help in getting to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, sorted it by upgrading to tfs2012

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the default port  8080 to port 80 and everything worked fine. but the message could also happen due to wrong saved credentials. you can go to the control panel of the windows and search for credentials manager and then remove your TFS credentials.

Comment: Based on the details provided by the question, I don't think that solves the problem in this situation. Were you getting the exact same error?(After all, some products do display very inaccurate network errors.)

Comment: My answer is an exact solution for the exact same error message. if you notice the picture in the question the port is 8080, so my answer points to the very same problem. now, why do think it is irrelevant? what is your evidence?

Comment: I'm not saying it didn't work for you... but this question starts with "it has suddenly stopped working". I'm not saying you are wrong... just asking questions that come to mind. For example, you could be right, it could have been a client upgrade changed the default port, and then you changed your port... and that might even the situation described in the question. (Vendors have done that... I think I worked for a couple, but thankfully I can't remember which products did that).

Comment: you are right benc, in this case, the cause of the problem could also be the wrong saved credentials . and can be solved by removing saved credential in credential manager.